# Angular 2 Redux initialState and interface of initialState

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm just starting to learn about the Redux Architecture (with Angular 2).

Do I understand it correctly that **everything** goes into **one** Object, which defines the state of the entire application?

If so, say I want to build a medium-sized app like an admin panel and I don't know all the properties/states yet. Would the work practice be to update the initialState and it's interface on the go?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I understand it correctly that **everything** goes into **one** Object, which defines the state of the entire application?

This is not entirely correct. - It *is* technically possible, but not adviced.

Data is usually aggregated into smaller chunks with semantic dependencies into `reducers` - if you look at the [ngrx-example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src/app/reducers) - you have the following `reducers` (you might call them *"sub-states"*):

- **books** -> contains everything book-related
- **collections** -> contains everything book-collection-related
- **layout** -> everything layout-related (if the side-panel is open or closed)
- **search** -> everything search-related

Now, technically every `reducer` is placed in the global store-object(just in case that you meant this by "*one* Object"), but that is just for convenience, a `reducer` has to be built as a *"standalone-component"* without the knowledge of other `reducers` and states.

So in summary: Use multiple `reducers`, not one big one.

> [...] say I want to build a medium-sized app like an admin panel and I don't know all the properties/states yet. Would the work practice be to update the initialState and it's interface on the go?

This depends on the contents of your applications, typical `reducers` for an admin-panel could be:

- **users** -> user-data
- **configuration** -> general configurational related data
- **support** -> e.g. for support-requests from users
- **layout** -> layout-related things

Now this is just **one** way of defining your reducers, there are plenty of applications where it might be better not divide the reducers by business-logic, but by some other criteria. ngrx is just a tool - you'll still have to do the thinking!

About updating the `interface` and `initialState`, I don't see why this should be a problem in any case - just add the new fields, implement the `reducer-cases` and you're done (ofc implement a display in some component ect...).